# Unexpected Output of System.out.print statement

Tags: java, string, equals

When used String's intern method in program it gives some unexpected output i'm unable to understand why this gives such output

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String str1 = "patty";
        String str2 = new String("patty");

        System.out.println("1   ->  "+ str1 == str2);

        String str3 = str2.intern();

        System.out.println("2   ->  "+ str1 == str3);
    }
}
```

in output it shows

```
false
false
```

but the expected output is

```
1   ->  false
2   ->  true
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this problem

Comment: you have to use `.equals` to compare strings

Comment: how exactly is this 'unexpected'?

Comment: i'm just trying to compare two references using intern method so i used == insted of .equals

Comment: It is really well explained in this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interning-of-string/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `str1` and `str3` reference the same `String` instance, you are not comparing these references.

```
System.out.println("2   ->  "+ str1 == str3);
```

compares `"2   ->  "+ str1` to `str3`.

Try:

```
System.out.println("2   ->  "+ (str1 == str3));
```

Comment: ok got it thank you

Comment: @vishals. you need to accept the answer if it answered your question, so that others know it's been answered.

Comment: yes i will accept it but before 10 minutes i can't accept it so i will accept it in 10 minutes after answered